Formatting text B that appears by hovering over text A created in RMarkdown
I have this text in Markdown:
`This is assessed by examining the <abbr title="The 75-25 ratio shows the average of the top 25% (or quartile) of people in a community as multiples of the bottom 25%. For example, if the 75-25 income ratio is 2, then it means the richest quartile has twice the income of the poorest quartile.">75-25 ratio</abbr> and the Gini coefficient.`

It works in that explanatory text appears in a text box when I hover over "75-25 ratio" and I like that there is a fuzzy line under this term (see below). But, I want to format the pop-up explanatory text by inserting a new line between its sentences, and making the font larger and some of it bold.

